# Design an algorithm to match trajectory?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a dataset in the form of (timestamp,latitude,longitude). I'm going to be given n entries where each entry is of the form of (timestamp,latitude,longitude). This is for one user.

```
User1:(timestamp1,latitude1,longitude1)....(timestamp_n,latitude_n,longitude_n)
```

Now let's say we have 100 users each has a set of points of (timestamp,latitude,longitude)

I want to know which set of users might have matching trajectory.
Matching trajectory would be the same route taken, hence in a given set of timestamps the latitude and longitude should be same or close enough as well as the timestamp should be same or close enough. Close enough can be about 30 seconds for timestamp while for space let it be like 200 metres. I can do this via a brute force approach and I'm looking for better solutions.

Comment: Could you be specific about what "matching trajectory" is? Are you referring to the direction determined by the last two points in time for a given user? Or some longer term time average?

Comment: Do the timestamps have to match as well in this case?

Comment: Too vague. Be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [k-dtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) or a [range tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree) to index your data.  These will let you efficient perform a range query over all three dimensions to your data.

Comment: You are saying to have 3kd trees each for timestamp,lattitude and longitude respectively?

Comment: @gizgok That's correct. There may be a way to accomplish this with only one tree, but nothing comes to mind

Comment: @gizgok I forgot that you can implement a multi dimensional kd-tree or range tree; see my revised answer

Comment: O'Pootertot Do you know of any implementation of kd-tree which does the multi-dimension part.

Comment: @gizgok My mistake, I'm confusing a kd-tree with an interval tree. A kd-tree already takes into account that you have high-dimensional data (in this case 3-dimensional data), so you should be able to use any kd-tree implementation straight out of the box

Answer (score 1):

This is quite unrelated to whether the algorithm will still be bruteforce or not.

What I want to present here is **how to measure the difference between 2 paths**.
It just that I think defining precisely how to quantify the difference will be important.
If you want something faster, then you can probably **approximate** this quantity later.

Ok, I think the difference between 2 paths is:

```
The average distance between 2 users over time.
```

You should be able to interpolate between 2 given data points to find out where the user is at any given time. Just linear interpolation might suffice.

When I say average over time, one would discretize the time so it is easier to compute.
Let's say:

```
The average distance between 2 users every 10 seconds period.
```

---

Edit: The above suggestion assumed that you care about "timing".
Since you mention the timestamp and all.
If you didn't care about it, you shouldn't have put it into the question in the first place.

Anyway, I kind of imagine that it is possible you want to just look at the path itself.
In that case, you could still use the above definition of path difference
simply by ignoring the actual timestamp and imagine that the users start at the same time at the begining of the paths.
The travel speed can be set in various ways... such as making both users complete the path at the same time no matter if one path is longer than another, or maybe just let both travel at the same speed.

Anyway, it all comes down to defining **how do you want to measure the path difference**.
You need to give more details in the question.